# Updating a property in a ObservableCollection WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I seem to be having a issue with updating a `ListView` with the data being changed in an `ObservableCollection`.

so I have a class called `Items` which inherits from the `INotifyPropertyChanged` class and implements the property change handler.

I then have an `ObservableCollection` of items which is then set to the source of a `CollectionViewSource`.

The `List` then binds to the `CollectionViewSource`.

When I change the data of a property in the `ObservableCollection` it will trigger the property change but not update the UI.

I've spent a while looking for solutions but most are for WPF which has a load of depreciated functions and from what I've read is that the WinRT `ObservableCollection` should just update when a property is changed.

I'm sure though that I am missing something otherwise it would be working for me.

Comment: Can you provide the code of your Items class (mainly the implementation of that property) as well as your XAML (where you bind that property)?

Comment: What do you mean by "change the data of a property in the observable collection"? What are the items in the collection, do they implement the INotifyPropertyChanged as well?

Comment: I got it working in the end it was a mistake somewhere else in the code which caused me to think that the Observable collection was not updating the UI correctly.